# Do prisons offer electricity to inmates 24/7?

Tags: realism, black-bird

In the TV show, [*Black Bird*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bird_(miniseries)) (2022), Jimmy is given the case file of a serial killer in prison and he starts reading it during one evening in his cell.

[image]

I am not really sure how realistic this is. I would imagine a prison would limit the freedom, including access to light; also I vaguely remember in other movies / dramas, they would have a cutoff time after which electricity is cut from within all cells (I could be wrong).

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me these days. Last time I was in a prison [a closed one, we were filming there] it even had a 50m swimming pool!

Comment: @Tetsujin, this pool is open to inmates? not just for prison employees?

Comment: Judging by its placing, yes. There was no-one to ask - the entire place was closed down, abandoned.

Comment: Well inmates aren't given case files too. So I am guessing that it must have been a special privilege apart from general privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Missouri, USA, at least, you can have fans and/or alarm clocks in your cell.  Also, they mention MP3 players, which presumably need electricity as well.

See pages 7 to 9 of this MO Prisoner's Handbook:
https://www.bop.gov/locations/institutions/spg/SPG_aohandbook.pdf

So, in conclusion, it is allowable in some prisons.  It's my understanding they prefer electricity to battery-powered due to batteries placed in socks and used as weapons.

Comment: This one is set in Milan federal institution in Michigan.

Comment: @user133469 - Page 3, rule 7.  http://www.micpr.org/uploads/8/9/7/1/8971956/prisoner_guidebook_-_mdoc.pdf

Comment: Thanks! There is still the open question of whether the electricity is turned off to the cells at night. I think that is what the question is asking here.

Comment: @user133469 - If it's turned off at night, everyone's alarm clocks are gonna be wrong.  :-)